# Android - Problem executing a asynch task and executing a thread

Tags: android

Can someone help me with this code?  All I'm trying to do is determine whether the device's internet connection is available in a separate Connection class with an asynch task and return the result to my splash screen activity.  If the connection isn't active, I want to throw a dialog alert saying it isn't active and then terminate the app.   I can't get the asynch task to fire off and return a non-null result.

Splash.java:

```
package com.nwp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class Splash extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    initSplash();   

    }

private void initSplash()
{    
     final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, 
             getResources().getString(R.string.splashCheckInterenetConnection), 
             getResources().getString(R.string.splashPleaseWait), true);  

     Connection.context = this;
     if(!Connection.isOnline());
     {   
         AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         dlgAlert.setMessage(R.string.splashNoInternetConnection);
         dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
         dlgAlert.setNeutralButton("Ok", 
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                 
             // click listener on the alert box                
             public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)      {                    
                 // the button was clicked                    
                 dialog.dismiss();
                 finish();               
                 }            
             });

         dlgAlert.create().show();



     }

}


}
```

Connection.java:

```
package com.nwp;

import android.content.Context;  
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
public class Connection {

public static Context context;
private static Boolean connectedInternet;

public static Boolean isOnline()
{

     new isOnlineAsync().execute(context);
     return Connection.connectedInternet;
}


// Check Internet Connection 
 private static class isOnlineAsync extends AsyncTask<Context, String, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) contexts[0].getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo(); 
            boolean OnlineState = netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected();
            return OnlineState;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);

      Connection.connectedInternet = result;



    }  

 }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
 new isOnlineAsync().execute(context);
 return Connection.connectedInternet;
```

Those two lines run one after another and the `AsyncTask` runs asynchronously (surprise, surprise). That means `Connection.connectedInternet` is getting called before the `AsyncTask` finishes. The easiest way to deal with this that I can think of is to make the `AsyncTask` an inner class of the Activity, and do the `if(!Connection.isOnline())` etc. stuff in the `onPostExecute`. If you want to reuse the `AsyncTask` in many places, you could require a callback to be passed in the constructor that would be called instead.

**Update:**

Actually, after coming back to this, it would make sense to me to not pass the callback in, but simply bake it into the `AsyncTask`. Instead of doing:

```
new isOnlineAsync().execute(context);
```

do:

```
new isOnlineAsync(){
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(!Connection.isOnline())
        {
            // ...   
        }
    }
}.execute(context);
```

Just as a side-note, start your classes with a capital letter, so call it `IsOnlineAsync` instead of `isOnlineAsync`.

Comment: Thanks. I think you're totally right, and that's what I'm interested in doing:  reusing the the Async task rather than having a one time use on the activity page. I am not clear on how I would setup a callback to be passed in the constructor.  Is there an example of that somewhere?

Comment: Updated to address the callback issue.

Comment: Thanks--I think that's the solution I'm looking for. And I'll adjust the case on my class as well.  Just curious, going back to the original two lines:   new IsOnlineAsync().execute(context); return Connection.connectedInternet;   Is there a way of waiting for the first line that starts the Async task to complete, e.g. getting some type of notification that its completed its task in the original calling method?

Comment: No, not without blocking. If you "wait" in the middle of the method, you're blocking the thread. In this case that's the UI thread. Blocking the UI thread would mean your app becomes unresponsive which you don't want.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Thanks again for clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> 
    {
        private ProgressDialog progress;
        private Context context;
        public BackgroundTask(Context context) 
        {
            this.context=context;
            progress=new ProgressDialog(context);
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
                        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity == null) 
        {
            //boitealerte(this.getString("No Internet Connection"),"getSystemService rend null");
        }
        else
        {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                {
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) 
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
        return false;
          }
     protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Checking...", "Please Wait", true,true);
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            progress.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(Update.this,"Show result here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Update.this.finish();
        }
```

you can return false from onPostExecute() and then check it in calling class, and show the alert dialog according to return value.